# VueJS: Build process inserts junk characters

Tags: vue.js

### Problem

During development (`yarn run dev`) everything looks and operates normally. When I `yarn run build`, the resulting `dist` includes a bunch of junk characters. For example, `&copy` becomes `Â©` and `&mdash;` becomes `â€”`.

[image]

### Context

- "vue": "2.3.2"
- "vue-meta": "^1.5.8"
- "vue-router": "^2.5.3"
- "vuex": "^2.3.1"

Comment: is your encoding set to `utf-8`?

Comment: Yes, like so: `<meta charset="utf-8">`.

Comment: You prompted me to take a second look and this _is_ the problem. I was using `vue-meta` to dynamically set this attribute along with everything else in the `<head>`. I moved this single attribute out of `vue-meta` and back into `index.html` and it solved the issue.

Comment: Leave your comment as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: glad it worked - will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure encoding is set to `utf-8` in your `index.html` page. It should have a `head` entry of:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`