# Error loading minified javascript build with vue-cli (and webpack / babel) in Google Chrome served with FastAPI and passed through Jinja templating

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, jinja2, fastapi

When I try to rebuild the filebrowser.org frontend based on Vue.js 2 using:

```
yarn install ; yarn build
```

the minified javascript files have invalid unicode characters. When I look into the file, I see some junk in moment.js locales, especially in the "he" locale:

```
...weekdays:"یه<200c>كشه<200c>ممه<200c>_دووشه<200c>ممه<200c>_سێشه<200c>ممه<200c>_چوارشه<200c>ممه<200c>_پێنج...

...c8d2:function(e,t,n){var r=n("d039"),a=n("5899"),i="<200b><85><180e>";e.exports=function(e){return...
```

A javascript error is displayed on the browsers console window during loading. When I remove the <200b> char, the page does load.

The charset line in the main `index.html` page which imports everything is:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

See also: [VueJS: Build process inserts junk characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54789038/vuejs-build-process-inserts-junk-characters)

EDIT 1:

I'm not sure anymore if this really has to do with `moment.js` (title changed):

- When I run filebrowser in command mode and download and save the generated javascript `js/chunks-vendor*.js` it contains also:

  ```
  i="<200b><85><180e>"
  ```
- When serving the same JS gotten from filebrowser with FastAPI, I get `chunk-vendors.c2bca31f.js:281 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`. Both apps serve the file with content type: `application/javascript; charset=utf-8`

EDIT 2: It seems that it has nothing to do with vue-cli / webpack / babel minifying,  because serving those with:

```
  yarn serve --mode production
```

renders correctly.

Comment: So the issue is not the file itself (and thus Webpack/Babel/Vue-CLI), but the application that reads it from disk and serves it to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minified JavaScript passes through Jinja2 templating to replace some template variables, but this produces invalid JS:

```py
@app.get(STATIC_URL + '/{file_path:path}', include_in_schema=False)
async def serve_static(request: Request, file_path: str):
    if not file_path:
        file_path = 'index.html'
    if file_path.endswith(('.html', '.js')):
        return templates.TemplateResponse(
            file_path,
            {'request': request, 'Name': NAME, 'StaticURL': STATIC_URL, 'Json': JSON},
            media_type='application/javascript; charset=utf-8' if file_path.endswith('.js') else None,
        )
    return FileResponse(os.path.join(STATIC_DIR, file_path))
```

So it has nothing to do with vue-cli / webpack / babel.

Jinja2 seems to translate `\x85` into `\n`. The JS polyfill for String.trim / trimStart / trimEnd includes the the string `'\u200B\u0085\u180E'` so this will be translated to `'\u200b\n\u180e'` producing invalid JS.